# JQuery ajax not working when passing ip address in data with parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

the ajax method is not working when I'm passing ip address or any other parameter which has some special character.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
                data: '{ name: ' + name + ', Ip:' + ip + '}',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
```

There is one solution by encoding the input in base 64. is there any other way ?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens, why is that wrong, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The mistake here is that you try to assemble a JSON string manually - don’t _ever_ do that.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **CBroe** said,you should not assemble a JSON string manually,

Due to your parameter might have some special characters,I would advice your do not use `json` to send parameters.

you can remove `contentType` and change data to `{name:name,Ip:ip}` to send the parameters directly

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //remove it
        url: '/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
        data: {name:name,Ip:ip},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
});
```

Comment: But then its not sending JSON, it seems like OP wants to send JSON.

Comment: @Musa yeah,my answer is a non `json` solution

Answer (score 1):

Create a object and use that in `data` property of the AJAX request which will fix your problem:

```
var dataObj = {
  name: name,
  Ip: ip
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: '/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
  data: dataObj,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    alert(response.d);
  },
  failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.d);
  }
});
```